# how to clear all list in ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm working in ionic 2 project, created swipe to delete each items working fine and also need click button delete all items How can I delete all items from a list in angular 2?

```
<button ion-button clear>Clear All</button>    
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let note of notes">
          <ion-item>
              {{note.title}}
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item-options>
              <button (click)="deleteNote(note)" danger>
                  <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
              </button>
          </ion-item-options>
        </ion-item-sliding>
```

file.ts

```
constructor( public viewCtrl: ViewController ) { 
    this.notes = [
      { title: 'This is notification swipe to delete' },
      { title: 'This is notification swipe to delete' }    
      ];
  }
deleteNote(note){

        let index = this.notes.indexOf(note);

        if(index > -1){
            this.notes.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `clear()` method like this

```
public clear(): void {
  this.notes = [];
}
```

And call it from the view

```
<button ion-button clear (click)="clear()">Clear All</button>
```